# How to use map in spark without implementing Serializable?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I used `map()` in my code and it throwed a `NotSerializableException`, so I implemented `Serializable`.

Is there any other way to overcome this exception or does map always use `Serializable`?

```
Dataset<Row> outdf=indf.map(new MapFunction<Row,Row>() {

    @Override
    public Row call(Row row){
          //Calling another function in another class 
 
       return r;//r is also a row
     }
},encoder);
```

Comment: What is it that implements `Serializable` in your solution?

Comment: The class where I use this code.My class name is Mapping so it's class Mapping implements Serializable

Comment: If you show us where you use this class, it might give us some clue

Answer (score 0):

Inside the call function, if you are using something(variable,object) which is in your Mapping class, then this Mapping class needs to implement Serializable.

Refer to this [article](https://medium.com/onzo-tech/serialization-challenges-with-spark-and-scala-a2287cd51c54).